# SWIFTUI - Picker view touch/scroll-able area is still out of frame even after using clipped()

Tags: swiftui

SWIFTUI 
I have a picker view(wheel type) and I clipped() its frame to half width of the screen, and from the UI you can see its half but the scrollable area is still actionable outside that frame.
How can I remove that outer area to not be scrollable?

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Picker(selection: self.$viewModel.selectedFrameworkIndex, label: Text("")) {
    ForEach(0 ..< viewModel.Categories.count) {
        Text(self.viewModel.Categories[$0])
            .foregroundColor((self.colorScheme == .dark) ? Color.white : Color.black)
         }
    }
    .frame(width: width / 2) // width is width of my screen
    .clipped() 
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 with replicated code. Maybe the reason is somewhere else. What (where from) is `width`? Would you show more your code?

Comment: I think you don't need to use `clipped` method as long as setting frame is correct. Nevertheless you want to force the touch event enabled in the frame area, just try to append `.contentShape(Rectangle())` right after `clipped`. It sets the hit testing area explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Add .compositingGroup() after .clipped()

```
HStack(spacing: 0) {
Picker(selection: self.$viewModel.selectedFrameworkIndex, label: Text("")) {
ForEach(0 ..< viewModel.Categories.count) {
    Text(self.viewModel.Categories[$0])
        .foregroundColor((self.colorScheme == .dark) ? Color.white : Color.black)
     }
}
.frame(width: width / 2) // width is width of my screen
.clipped() 
.compositingGroup()  }
```

Comment: No longer works on iOS 15.1

Comment: Any solution for iOS 15.1+

Answer (score 2):

Adding this `extension` worked for me:

```
extension UIPickerView {
    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  `.scaleEffect()` works well for me. Please check [Clickable area of SwiftUI Picker overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72163536/19312666)