# Clickable area of SwiftUI Picker overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

I am currently trying to create a page with three adjacent `Picker` views inside of an `HStack` as seen below:

[image]

I made a `CustomPicker` view where I limit the frame to 90 x 240, and then use `.compositingGroup()` and `.clipped()` to make the selectable area of each picker not overlap.

**CustomPicker.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomPicker: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let pickerColor: Color
    
    var numbers: some View {
        ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { num in
            Text("\(num)")
                .bold()
        }
    }
    
    var stroke: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
    }
    
    var backgroundColor: some View {
        pickerColor
            .opacity(0.25)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Numbers", selection: $selection) {
            numbers
        }
        .frame(width: 90, height: 240)
        .compositingGroup()
        .clipped()
        .pickerStyle(.wheel)
        .overlay(stroke)
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .cornerRadius(16)
    }
}
```

**ChoicePage.swift**

```
struct ChoicePage: View {
    @State var choiceA: Int = 0
    @State var choiceB: Int = 0
    @State var choiceC: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 18) {
            CustomPicker(selection: $choiceA, pickerColor: .red)
            CustomPicker(selection: $choiceB, pickerColor: .green)
            CustomPicker(selection: $choiceC, pickerColor: .blue)
        }
    }
}
```

When testing both `CustomPicker` and `ChoicePage` in the preview canvas and simulator, it had worked perfectly fine, but when I tried to use it on my physical devices (iPhone 8 and iPhone 13, both on iOS 15.1) the clickable areas overlap. I have tried solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110421/how-to-stop-a-swiftui-picker-from-reacting-to-touches-outside-its-visible-area) and [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687986?answerId=685001022#685001022), as well as many others, but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: There's no way to have the native picker work correctly in iOS 15.1, see my `UIViewRepresentable` solution idea at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122169/ios15-swiftui-wheelpicker-scrollable-outside-frame-and-clipped-area-destructin/69842277#69842277

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65631488/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi I just tested using `.contentShape(Rectangle())` and it did not work. I answered the original post with an adjusted solution from [Steve M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817031/steve-m)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

adding this extension is working for me in 15.4

```
extension UIPickerView {   
   open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {     
      return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)} 
}
```

found at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687986?answerId=706782022#706782022

Answer (score 5):

I have a workaround for iOS 15+.

Use .scaleEffect(x: 0.5) to half the touchable area, of the Inline picker.

This will however also squish the text inside it, to fix this, apply .scaleEffect(x: 2), ONLY to the text inside the ForEach.

```
  var body: some View {
      Picker(selection: $number, label: Text(""), content: {
            ForEach(0..<21) {value in
            Text("\(value)").tag(number)
                .scaleEffect(x: 3)
            }
        }
    )
    .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
    .scaleEffect(x: 0.333)
}
```

[image: Screenshot of result, where the touchable area of the picker is smaller in width]

Comment: Awesome idea. Only issue is, that it messes up the rounded corners of the selection area. But for me it's no problem, because I clip them anyway

Comment: It works for me. Simple but effective! Thank you. However, it seems like to be only suitable for pickers in the same hstack. Is there any way to solve the overlapping issue of pickers in the same vstack?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by modifying the solution from [Steve M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1817031/steve-m), so all the credit for this goes to him.

He uses a `UIViewRepresentable`, but in his implementation, it's for three different selections inside of one. I slightly adjusted his implementation, to be used for just one value to select from in a given picker.

I start with `BasePicker`, which acts as the `UIViewRepresentable`:

**BasePicker.swift**

```
struct BasePicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    var selection: Binding<Int>
    let data: [Int]
    
    init(selecting: Binding<Int>, data: [Int]) {
        self.selection = selecting
        self.data = data
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> BasePicker.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<BasePicker>) -> UIPickerView {
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIPickerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<BasePicker>) {
        guard let row = data.firstIndex(of: selection.wrappedValue) else { return }
        view.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
        var parent: BasePicker
        
        init(_ pickerView: BasePicker) {
            parent = pickerView
        }
        
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 90
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return parent.data.count
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return parent.data[row].formatted()
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            parent.selection.wrappedValue = parent.data[row]
        }
    }
}
```

I then use the `BasePicker` Representable inside of `CustomPicker`, which is a SwiftUI `View`. I did this to make it a bit easier to keep my previous styling/structure in the original code.

**CustomPicker.swift**

```
struct CustomPicker: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    let pickerColor: Color

    let numbers: [Int] = Array(stride(from: 0, through: 100, by: 1))
    
    var stroke: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
    }
    
    var backgroundColor: some View {
        pickerColor
            .opacity(0.25)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        BasePicker(selecting: $selection, data: numbers)
            .frame(width: 90, height: 240)
            .overlay(stroke)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .cornerRadius(16)
    }
}
```

I then just need to slightly change `ChoicePage` and it's fixed. Also, take note that I moved the `numbers` array into my `CustomPicker` view, but you adust it so that you can pass it in from `ChoicePage` if you wanted.

**ChoicePage.swift**

```
struct ChoicePage: View {
    @State var choiceA: Int = 0
    @State var choiceB: Int = 0
    @State var choiceC: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 18) {
            CustomPicker(selection: $choiceA, pickerColor: .red)
            CustomPicker(selection: $choiceB, pickerColor: .green)
            CustomPicker(selection: $choiceC, pickerColor: .blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me and that avoid overlapping gestures between multiple Pickers. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer.  Anyone know how to make this more generic in case each picker has a different Type.  I'm using enums to back my picker and am trying to convert this.